# new to JavaScript, simple if function

Tags: javascript, node-red

I just made the jump from IDE to Node-RED where JavaScript comes into play. I am eager to learn but my knowledge is limited knowledge.

What I am trying to do, is simple to check the `msg.payload`, if the value is larger than 25 then I want to return 1 else I want to return 0.

I have tried different codes, but it does not work.

```
m = msg.payload;
if (m < 25)
{
  return 1;
}
else if (m > 25)
{
  return 0;
}
```

and

```
m = msg.payload;
if (m < 25)
{
  return 1;
}
  else ()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You simply have to change `<` to `>`, no?

Comment: You must return a `msg` object from a Node-RED function node, not just a value. Convention says you return the value as `msg.payload`

Answer (score 1):

For Node-RED function nodes you must return a `msg` object not just a value.

So the correct form for this test is as follows.

```
if (msg.payload > 25) {
  msg.payload = 1
} else {
  msg.payload = 0;
}

return msg;
```

Comment: Thanks! this was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn **[`comparision operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)** where **`>`** denotes **`greater than`** and **`<`** denotes **`lesser than`** , you can simplify  using ternary operator as

```
return msg.payload > 25 ? 1 : 0;
```

**`DEMO WITH IF ELSE`**

```js
function check(m){
if (m > 25){
    return 1;
  }
    else 
    {
      return 0;
    }
};

console.log(check(50));
```

**`DEMO WITH TERNARY`**

```js
function check(m){
  return m > 25 ? 1 : 0; 
};

console.log(check(50));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line:

```
return msg.payload > 25 ? 1 : 0;
```

or if you just need booleans (true/false):

```
return msg.payload > 25;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (Number(m) > 25){
    return 1;
}
else{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making a very silly mistake of **less than** and **greater than** sign. Hope it helps you.

```
m = msg.payload;
if (m > 25)
{
msg.payload=1;
}
else if (m < 25)
{
msg.payload=0;
}
return msg;
```

Comment: Your two examples are not equivalent, so they may be confusing to a beginner.

Comment: What sort of confusion ? and what is not equivalent ? They both are exactly same and works in exactly same fashion. I don't think a beginner will get any confusion. It was just a silly mistake.

Comment: They're not exactly the same. What happens if `m` is `25`.

Comment: Read the question. The question doesn't care for m=25. Following strictly the question.

Comment: First, irrespective of the question, *they're not equivalent* as you claim. Second, maybe you should read the question *"if the value is larger than 25 then I want to return 1 **else I want to return 0**."*. So if it's not greater than 25, it may be equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this a good bit, the `else` isn't even needed in this case:

```
if (m > 25) {
  return 1;
}
return 0;
```

When the `return` inside the `if` statement is executed, the code that follows won't be run... making the `else` statement unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

The else is redundant when you're just returning like that, and you've got your comparison operators backwards. Right now it'll return 1 if it's less than 25, not greater than.

```
if (msg.payload > 25) {
return 1;
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that you want to return 1 if value is greater than 25. Please check that you have written wrong condition.
Your condition must be this:

```
if ( m > 25 ){ 
    return 1; 
} else { 
    return 0; 
}
```